Ubuntu Core: unable to connect by SSH the second time after installation
I have just installed Ubuntu Core 24 on a small computer with the preinstalled ISO Amd64.  It is configured with a Wifi network at home with a local dynamic IP (DHCP).
I have installed my SSH public keys on my account Ubuntu One.
The first time, I am able to connect to fresh installed Ubuntu Core by SSH from my default computer (Linux Mint).
I have checked my SSH keys are on .ssh/authorized_keys in the Ubuntu Core.  My 2 keys are there.
When I reboot and I try to reconnect on my Ubuntu Core, it refuses the connection and ask for a password.
After that, I have installed Ubuntu Core many times with different changes but it does not work.
I try to connect with this command:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ubuntucore fndemers@192.168.0.103

My public key is in id_ubuntucore.pub
On the client, my .ssh folder is 700 access.  My .ssh/id_ubuntucore* are 600 access.
Here is the verbose result:
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022                                                                                                                                    
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                                                                                                                         
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files                                                                                                     
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *                                                                                                                                    
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.103 is address                                                                                                                                
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/demers/.ssh/known_hosts'                                                                                                    
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/demers/.ssh/known_hosts2'                                                                                                  
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering                                                                                                                                                           
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.103 [192.168.0.103] port 22.                                                                                                                                   
...
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 4 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/demers/.ssh/id_ubuntucore RSA SHA256:hKuBcQLiGoFbm+I2+5A0RQyYUQVAxJOvj/vlv9LE0Js explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: fndemers@... RSA SHA256:OFxIGmD2O2i6BCqbaE/AU+YUHkXlDX4kAZJ9xxuyFjw agent
debug1: Will attempt key: demers@XPS-15-9520 RSA SHA256:VGK27XLFpbfCb9KfqIebHygaUqj9yijSLLELrC6+jF4 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: fndemers RSA SHA256:0v+2eWeEKF7PiO9biiaJ/49haIWqLcXqa8TEnCSAsDo agent 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ec
dsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,pw
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,pw
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,pw
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,pw
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/demers/.ssh/id_ubuntucore RSA SHA256:hKuBcQLiGoFbm+I2+5A0RQyYUQVAxJOvj/vlv9LE0Js explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,pw
debug1: Offering public key: fndemers@... RSA SHA256:OFxIGmD2O2i6BCqbaE/AU+YUHkXlDX4kAZJ9xxuyFjw agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,pw
debug1: Offering public key: demers@XPS-15-9520 RSA SHA256:VGK27XLFpbfCb9KfqIebHygaUqj9yijSLLELrC6+jF4 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,pw
debug1: Offering public key: fndemers RSA SHA256:0v+2eWeEKF7PiO9biiaJ/49haIWqLcXqa8TEnCSAsDo agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,pw
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup pw
debug3: remaining preferred: ,pw
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled pw
debug1: Next authentication method: pw
fndemers@192.168.0.103's pw: 

There is something I have made wrong.  Please help me.
Regards,
Francois

How did you determine the IP address of the rebooted Ubuntu Core system?

By my rooter (DHCP).  The IP changes often.  At the second boot, the IP has changed.  But does it matter?

You wrote "The first time, I am able to connect to fresh installed Ubuntu Core by SSH from my default computer (Linux Mint)." That suggests your keys are correct, your IP address (pre-reboot) is correct, and the Ubuntu Core was successfully installed and working properly. That seems to leave two possibilities: A changed IP address or whatever changes you made during that first successful SSH session.
